# Using reflection to get a nested property value

Tags: .net, reflection

I have the following scenario:

```
class A
{
   string Foo;
}

Class B
{
   A PropertyA;
}

Class C
{
   B PropertyB;
}
```

Is it possible using .NET reflection to get the value of A.Foo if I start with object C? The problem I am running into is this:
I get to A through PropertyInfo objects. However, they don't have the instance information stored with them. Therefore, I can't do GetProperty("Foo").GetValue(....) since I only have object of type C passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the object returned by each property, then use the same reflection procedure on that instance to get the next "level" deep.

For example:

```
 C instance = GetMyCInstance();

 B propertyB = instance.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyB").GetValue(instance) as B;
 A propertyA = propertyB.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyA").GetValue(propertyB) as A;
 string Foo = propertyA.GetType().GetProperty("Foo").GetValue(propertyA) as string;
```

Comment: `B propertyB = instance.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyB").GetValue(instance, null) as B;` is what worked for me, thanks.